# How can I know whether user has logged in through facebook account or through Site login?

Tags: 7, users, social-network

How can I know whether user has logged in through FB or through site's login section? I am giving points to user based on FB login that's why It's important to know. Thanks

Comment: are you using contributed module to allow users to access Drupal through facebook or custom module?

Comment: Contributed module, I'm studying fb_stream, hopefully this will help, If you have any suggestion, you're welcome.

Comment: are you asking when a user logs in (each time) or when they initially register (one time) for your site?

Comment: Each time a user logs in

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Rules module](https://drupal.org/project/rules) together with [Notification module](https://drupal.org/project/notifications), to achieve what you want. There is no out of the box solution for this problem.

You will have to look into Adding a new rule to react to user registrations
Or to user logins. You will properly have to create a custom module depending on the deepth of what you exactly need

Comment: Thank you @Vic for your answer. I needed perhaps 5 months ago but I'll definitely try to implement it using rules. thank you.